# Using ansible synchronize to a directory of a different name

Tags: ansible, rsync

I am trying to use `ansible.posix.synchronize` to populate a remote directory tree from a local copy. The trouble I’m having is that I need the destination directory to be a different name from the source, and I don’t want the source name appearing as a subdirectory in the target.

I need this in a few places, but one particularly pernicious example is writing files into the remote user’s home directory, for example the task:

```yaml
- name: Add dot files
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: files/legacy/.
    dest: "{{ ansible_env['HOME'] }}/."
    owner: false
    group: false
```

…creates a `legacy` directory in the user home directory, containing the files I need to be at the root of the directory.

Since `ansible.posix.synchronize` is a wrapper around `rsync` I was hoping to use the `/.` suffix to synchronize the two directories without creating a subdirectory. Unfortunately, ansible “helpfully” normalizes the value of the `src` param (though not the `dest` param), and rsync doesn’t receive the argument with the trailing `/.`.

I either need some way to prevent that normalization from happening (only for this single task), or I need some way to mutate the file names as they pass through? I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I’ve looked at the documentation for `ansible.posix.synchronize` and it seems to be a straight wrapper around `rsync`. Poking into the module source code didn’t show anything obvious, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with Ansible.

From `man rsync`:

> A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating
> an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think of a
> trailing / on a source as
> meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the
> containing directory are transferred to
> the containing directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the following commands copies the files in the same way,
> including their setting of the attributes
> of `/dest/foo`:
>
> ```
> rsync -av /src/foo /dest
> rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
> ```

So it works as expected without the trailing dot:

```yaml
- name: Add dot files
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: files/legacy/
    dest: "{{ ansible_env['HOME'] }}/."
    owner: false
    group: false
```

If it doesn't help, you can try to use [`rsync_opts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#parameter-rsync_opts) or play with [`link_dest`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#parameter-link_dest).

Comment: Whale oil beef hooked! I was sure I tried that as well, and found that it was normalized down to the base directory name without the slash. But I just tried it again and it worked flawlessly. Thank you!